# "printf" does not work properly after any INT 10h interrupt call

Tags: c, printf, screen, dos, interrupt

Edited: Only printf with "\n" would be shown.

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  REGPACK   Regs;
  KEY_DATA  KeyData

  //Set cursor position AH= 02h, BH = Page Number, DH = Row, DL = Column
  Regs.h.ah = 0x02;
  Regs.h.bh = 0;
  Regs.h.dh = 15;
  Regs.h.dl = 40;
  intr(0x10, &Regs);

  printf("Test");

  while (KeyData.Key.ScanCode != SCAN_ESC)  {
   GetKey(&KeyData);
   printf("Key: %c", KeyCode.Key.AsciiChar);
  }
  return 0; 
}
```

The snippet is as above:

Coding Environment: Windows8.1
Tool chain: Open Watcom (WCL & WASM) v1.9
Executed on: DOSBox, real DOS 6.22

First, I found out that "printf" would not print anything on the screen, no *"Test"* nor *"Key: X"* is shown. Then I started to strike the keyboard, about 4~6 keystrokes, the string would come out in bunch, something like:

```
TestKey: aKey: bKey: cKey: d
```

The same symptoms occurred every 4~6 continuous keystrokes.

Another scenario, I didn't press anything, printf would not function, and as soon as I terminated this program by pressing "ESC", the two strings would be shown on the upper left of the screen, like there's nothing wrong.

So I began to think there is something wrong about this snippet, and printf only functions when DOS program terminate signal is occurred **(INT 21h AH=4Ch)**.

I've re-wrote the "set cursor position" thing in pure assembly, and did a near call to the proc, the bug still occurred, and I've changed the set cursor position to set video mode 3 from video mode 3 **(INT 10h, AH=00, AL=03h)** to refresh the screen, no luck, either.

No matter what method I used, after INT10h, the printf just wouldn't work before a DOS terminate signal.

Does anyone know why this happened? And is there a way to avoid this, or for me to use printf mixed with INT10h?

But **putc** and **puts** could print on the screen normally under this circumstances, and **printf only works when there is a "\n" character** (e.g. "helloworld\n"). I'm super confused...

I cannot abandon INT10h, because MSDOS has no native support of these kind of operation, and BIOS call is also effective, nor can I abandon printf, because variadic parameters really save my butt a lot.

Thanks guys!

Comment: quick comment, set your `Regs` to zero before you do anything else. The code you have may have unpredictable results dependent upon there.

Comment: Thanks KevinDTimm, but it doesn't solved.

Comment: This looks to be a buffering issue. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/).

Comment: @uesp, Wow! Thanks! It is the buffering issue! After I disabled the stdout buffering, printf worked!

Comment: I see you've added the solution to your question *and* posted it as an answer. I suggest deleting the added part of the question; it doesn't belong there. (I haven't checked that it's identical to the answer you posted, or I'd do it myself.)

Comment: @KeithThompson Ok, deleted. Still not used to the rules here, learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys! Finds out I'm really lack of this kind of knowledge.
Anyways, **if disabling stdout buffering, the whole thing works**.

Still don't know why it behaved so strangely after INT10h, and I'm expecting a big overhead on a big scale page print but at least it works for now. As below is the snippet.

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  REGPACK   Regs;
  KEY_DATA  KeyData

  //Disable stdout buffer
  setbuf(stdout, NULL);

  //Set cursor position AH= 02h, BH = Page Number, DH = Row, DL = Column
  Regs.h.ah = 0x02;
  Regs.h.bh = 0;
  Regs.h.dh = 15;
  Regs.h.dl = 40;
  intr(0x10, &Regs);

  printf("Test");

  while (KeyData.Key.ScanCode != SCAN_ESC)  {
   GetKey(&KeyData);
   printf("Key: %c", KeyCode.Key.AsciiChar);
  }
  return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
the indicated source would fail to successfully compile 
for several reasons, including:
1) two warnings about unused parameters argc and argv
2) unrecognized function: prtinf()

You can get 'immediate' output from printf calls by ending the 
format string with '\n' 
--or-- 
following the printf with the statement: fflush(stdout);
otherwise, the output is buffered until the OS feels like/has time to 
actually output it. (as for instance, when the program terminates
```